# How to compare dates with less than operator in mybatis XML in <if test = " "> block

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper

```
<if test= "birthdate lt '20-10-2000'">
```

it works but is there a better way which mybatis documentation approves?

Comment: It's XML, so you can write `>` which means you can write `<if test="'20-10-2000' > birthdate">`.

Comment: It does not work. syntax error in mybatis xml

Comment: If, by 'syntax error', you mean SQL syntax error, it's a different problem. Please add more info (complete statement, stack trace, TRACE level log, etc.) or share a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that reproduces the error.